Procedural rendering methods in TeX and easier ways to draw classic ("Roger Penrose") "hand-drawn" style pointillist filled illustrations in TikZ?
Is there an easier way to do in TIKZ some of the things hand-drawn illustrations do? (Think those by Roger Penrose or anything that was common in 1950's to 1970's McGraw-Hill, Prentice-Hall, and the rest. Yonder year when fine arts illustrators were employed.)
Example of style: 
(This style of illustration that was already here on TeXSe from an old post by D.R. who wrote he had hand drawn it.)

Clarification: No request is made for any particular image to be drawn. The question concerns methods and macro ideas for quality pointillism. Calculation is quite brittle in LaTeX so far as the OP knows how to do it.

It would be nice to be able to finally include such illustrations as code in a paper itself, right? Maybe something changed in two decades and there is now a package or a trick to make that? If not:
Proposed Approach: Like fill in areas with a) more or less dense nice points b) that all slightly differ in a pleasing to the eye way? Combined with lines of different densities?
(G1) My guess at this point is that the best way (Tikz) to automate some of the process would be to define several procedures that:
a) designate at the start one or more coordinate points (*)
b) take a path,
c) get distance of each point spaced with fineness that is a parameter in side the region bound by the path to *,
d) have thickness of lines or density of hatching or points fill inside a path increase nearer to these reference points and decrease with distance,
e) When two or more points, the density increases nonlinearly?
To make the question constructive, I would define this specific question upvoted and solved:

Implementing G1 as a method TikZ and seeing if it looks alright in cases the solver gets to choose. No specific let alone complex image needs to be recreated and partial solutions and other guesses to solutions are welcome.

Any better way? This is a discussion point and optional. Alternative way may be to have your favorite AI model generate coordinates for each point in a grid, with more or less on each of the four sides, but then crop using a path? But an enormous datafile of random positions is not a "good" way of embedding an illustration in a paper or book, does it not?

Appendix: AI is not the answer as of 2024. Anyway not yet.

Were we to try to use generative ai (this loses the embedded/editable condition and benefit) we get beautiful art that also lacks any real meaning. We are unable to specify the precise path. Much better a less comp
Example: Beautiful but meaningless...no... 
Example: Pointillist penrose style black and white crumpled cylinder...eh...definitely no... 

No code, no illustrations? You rely on the few who might have the required background? Sounds to me like a question closed quickly …

at the very least you should show images for the kind of diagrams you hav ein mind and the kind of input data you want to provide. As is there is (for almost everyone) just the names of some book publishers and no question at all.

I assumed everyone knows what I was talking about. Okay, will add an example of an image in a moment.

note that a question which just posts an image and expects solvers to do-this-complicated-thing-for-me is also liable to get closed. in addition to an image, some code with an explanation of the obstacle you've run into would be best. failing that, at least a sketch of the code showing the input format and explaining how it relates to the desired input (as @DavidCarlisle said).

why would you assume everyone would know what you mean by 'anything that was common in 1950's to 1970's'? Penrose makes me think tiling, but that hardly fits the description.

please link relevant previous posts on tex se. but I don't think this is a reasonable question for this site in its current form.

Not talking about any drawing complex images themselves. I was asking about pointillist methods. It is not obvious how to automate them well in a language like LaTeX. 2024: One can have your ai model of choice write a large random list of coordinates, within simple bounds, and draw a point of different scale on each one, but that is not a particularly good method, we are agreed?

Quite right, it is not the ideal question but that is probably why it has never been asked and perhaps no progress has been made on something like it? There may not be a good way to ask it, by those who want to ask it. The question probably is quite relevant though.

the image looks to me hand drawn and intended to look hand drawn, why would you generate such a picture with tikz which is designed to postion things to exact coordinates? "This style of illustration that was already here on TeXSe" link?

wouldn't you do something this (with a bit better tuning) rather than use tikz for such an image

or closer to the style you show

You could draw the grid and so on on one layer, define a second one with missing areas, dots etc., and finally use clipping and/or opacity. Not very different to what you‘d do with bitmaps.

Tikz can be part of the code of a paper and can be edited as code. Many benefits, as you can imagine. The challenge is usually the diagram must be precisely a particular shape. AI doesn't know that. Usually that can be well specified as a path, only the rendering with fill in "hand-drawn" style is the issue. The fill also has "some" formal meaning, but is random to a degree. Black and white is the next issue. I'll post some examples of AI making something very pretty but failing at meaning in a moment.

DC: The second image you posted is quite nice I agree. The issue is that having a simpler image in that style, embedded inside the text of a paper itself and editable by path parameters, but with the rendering, would be excellent. If possible. The questions wants to explore the possibility. The author can then precisely specify meaning as it changes when the paper changes. (The art style was quite common in older applied and engineering books. Penrose brought it to the fore in maths literature where it is also pleasant. As opposed to using Blender or a CAD and making a gray filled shape.)

Your edit refererred to the meaning of the images which is why in my original question I said you should show your intended input data as well as the desired output. You don't distinguish how can anyone but you distinguish the top image having some meaning from the lower ones that are meaningless. It is presumably your subject area, but assume all readers of this site have no more knowledge than chatgpt (ie no knowledge) if you want tex (or anything) to produce an image that relates to some data or a mathematical model (rather than a generative AI model) then you need to show that data.

The challenge is implementing generic procedures for filling and rendering and fine control hence hand-coding, implementing something like (G1) where authors can control form. There is no single common type of image supposed. Figure would depend on the paper content. What would be the same is tools for rendering? Process might be draw a line figure with \path etc. Now also shade it by selecting a few centers of density. Probability of a large point being drawn far from all centers eg 5 "centers of density" is very low, near 3 of them very high, eg. Outside path no chance. Then layering?

I don't see how anybody can answer this but you or another specialist. To the rest of us, you've shown three grayscale/black-and-white (not sure) images. what have you tried in tikz? if you can show us something you do manually and explain what you want to be able to parameterise, we could help with that. or if you can show us something with the parameterisation you want, but which gives undesired output, we could help you tweak it. you maybe want something like a library, but that's too big a question for this site, imho.

This just feels hopelessly open-ended to be answerable in any way more specific than “you can do lots of things in TikZ these days; read the manual and elsewhere to see what”. There are dozens of techniques that go into such an illustration, and different illustrations require different things. Narrow down to a specific illustration and a specific technical aspect — eg just how to get the dot-based shading like in that particular illustration from Penrose — and that’s a question that could work here.
